# Is there any way to control or predict which URL React chooses to host static media files?

Tags: reactjs

So when you include static assets in a React project, let's say a jpg image, they have to get hosted somewhere, right? The pattern used by React seems to be MY_WEBSITE/static/media/IMAGE_NAME.EIGHT_RANDOM_CHARACTERS.jpg.

I'm wondering if there is a way for me to either control the route or predict what those eight characters are going to be. I've searched through the React Docs for this and can't find anything.

I know that this might be a bit unusual/hacky. Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is give the many static image files bundled into the front-end application a predictable url where they are hosted at. Is this possible?

Comment: That's not what React does, it is your compiler! if you're using webpack, have a look at its loaders (usually the config lies at `url-loader` or `file-loader`) for the asset files. As for the js files, its at the `webpack.output.{filename,chunkFilename}`.

Comment: Yep, found it in the webpack docs, thanks. More information on the default create-react-app process here: https://medium.com/derek-gc/importing-local-images-in-react-with-webpack-86c50c337dc9

Turns out a much simpler way to do what I needed was putting my images in the public folder. According to React documentation, when you have a large volume of images whose url needs to be dynamically referenced, it's best practice anyway. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not reactjs related. I guess this is the result of a webpack build configured by `create-react-app`. `EIGHT_RANDOM_CHARACTERS` should be the hash of the file for caching purposes.

You will probably need to [npm run eject](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject) to get some control over [webpack configuration](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/configuration/).

Answer (score 1):

Although you can remove the contenthash applied to assets with custom webpack configuration, it turns out the best practice way to get predictable asset urls, at least according to the [create-react-app docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/), is putting the assets in the public folder. The assets will then be available at yourwebsite.com/your-path-here.

If you do want to remove the contenthash provided by webpack out of the box from create-react-app, [this article](https://medium.com/derek-gc/importing-local-images-in-react-with-webpack-86c50c337dc9) shows where that happens specifically in the webpack config file.